# Which other non-trained pitch detection algorithm is similar to PYIN in accuracy?

Tags: pitch, fundamental-frequency

Which other non-trained pitch detection algorithm is similar to PYIN in accuracy?

PYIN worked great for me, but all the code is GPL licenced or unavailable, so I am looking for an alternative?

Trained algorithms are out of the question, because I think gathering good samples for training is more difficult.